# Cannot start postgresql properly

Tags: postgresql

I cannot "`service postgresql start`" by `root`:

> Startup Log: /usr/bin/postmaster: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object:
>   Permission denied

I cannot "`service postgresql start`" by `postgres`:

> Startup Log:runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted

But I can start it by postgres user with command:

```
postmaster -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Why?

When I installed, I used

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

not

```
service postgresql initdb
```

So I afterwards changed `init.d/postgresql` script with the new path. Is this causing problem?

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem on the data directory. Did you check if the postgres (operating system) user has **full** access to  `/usr/local/pgsql/data` and all sub-directories?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Looks to me like zlib has the wrong permissions or SELinux label, m'self.

Comment: OP: what OS and version are you on? What version of PostgreSQL? How did you install PostgreSQL and from where? If it's CentOS or Fedora, are there any SELinux messages in the system log or dmesg?

Comment: CentOS5.6 PostgreSQL8.1.23  I installed by yum. Nothing in dmesg. What permission should zlib has? It's now owned by root. I chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql

Answer (score 2):

Caused for me by creating the DB with

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

Recreating with

```
service postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

solved the issue.

Comment: What should I do when i don't have "service" available?

Comment: @KaiThomasWerther and `pg_createcluster`?

Comment: Running the Scripts on init.d solved it. CentOs is weird when you are used to Windows ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Craig said this is either a file permission issue or a selinux issue.  If it is a file permissions issu, that is easy enough to fix (give read/execute perms).

If it is an selinux issue your best option is to run `audit2allow` to identify the problem and ensure that selinux is configured to allow the correct access.